# How do I let a program D read a memory location within the memory allocated to a program A?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++-2005

So I'd like to let read D read this memory location and do some work on it. Any thoughts? Is writing a debugger extension the only way - if so, any recommendations?

I considered executing a memory dump to file (still don't know how, AFAIK I can only view memory in a window) and letting D work on the file, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to read memory of another process. You should use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Wow, really? I thought you couldn't read outside the programs allocated region! Will check it out.

Answer (score 6):

if you need the two programs to share part of the memory you can use [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're apparently using Windows, the way for one process to look at another process' memory is with `ReadProcessMemory`. While it's certainly true that debuggers typically use this, using it is still well short of writing a debugger.